# How to literally get the `get_change_message` in `django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry` in django 2.2

Tags: python, django

I've added a code in my view to log every add action in my add_new_staff page. Here's the code:

```
            message = f'New user added. Added staff profile for {user.first_name} {user.last_name}'

            log = LogEntry.objects.log_action(
                user_id=request.user.id,
                content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(user).pk,
                object_id=repr(user.id),
                # or any field you wish to represent here
                object_repr=repr(user.username),
                action_flag=ADDITION,  # assuming it's a new object
                change_message=message,)  # a new user has been added

            log.save()
```

In here, I only made a custom get message thru `message` string. And I think, for this `add_staff_view` it is ok to do this. But now, I'm working on my `update_staff_profile_view` and also, I need to log this action. I saw how the change/update form in django admin page inserts the `change_message` in LogEntry model(it shows which fields are changed/updated), and I can't think of ways to do it inside my own update_staff_profile_view.

Here's my `update_staff_profile_view`:

```
@login_required
def ProfileUpdateView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = accounts_forms.UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if request.user.is_staff == True:
            profile_form = accounts_forms.StaffProfileUpdateForm(
                request.POST, instance=request.user.staffprofile)
        else:
            profile_form = accounts_forms.StudentProfileUpdateForm(
                request.POST, instance=request.user.studentprofile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()

            log = LogEntry.objects.log_action(
                user_id=request.user.id,
                content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(user).pk,
                object_id=repr(user.id),
                object_repr=str(user.username),
                action_flag=CHANGE,
                change_message = 'IM STUCK HERE',)

                log.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Your profile has been updated.')
            return redirect('update-profile')

    else:
        user_form = accounts_forms.UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        if request.user.is_staff == True:
            profile_form = accounts_forms.StaffProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.staffprofile)
        else:
            profile_form = accounts_forms.StudentProfileUpdateForm(
                instance=request.user.studentprofile)
    context = {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/update_profile.html', context)
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout  how it works in admin.py  this [link](https://github.com/django/django/search?q=change_message&unscoped_q=change_message) may help.

In your views.py you may do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import construct_change_message 

user_form = ModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=Obj)

if user_form.is_valid():
    user_form = form.save()
    change_message = construct_change_message(user_form, None, add)
```

Note that for me the variable add is False when editing the form otherwise True.

Comment: hi sir I just saw your answer, I'll make sure to try that. Thanks